# Modelling a book in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to model articles that consist of multiple, long parts. These parts should be accessible one by one, so that I can split the parts across pages and create table of contents. For editing I'd like both to be possible, editing one by one AND as a whole. This is pretty much what is possible with MediaWiki for ages now.

Simply having a ForeignKey in Part to Article has some shortcomings. You can't edit articles as whole and there's no sorting in parts, only a random list in the Django admin. Also I think it might have some bad impacts on performance as most articles would probably be shown as a whole at once, which would involve reverse ForeignKey resolutions.

Now how would you go about that? Are there some libraries or frameworks that ease such relations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**models.py**:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=X)
    ...

class Part(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=X)
    content = models.TextField()
    ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('order',)
```

You have to set order in each part, every query will return them ordered by this field.

Using [InlineModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) you can edit all parts of an article from its admin page.

There shouldn't be performance impacts: if queries are done properly all parts of an article (even all parts of multiple articles) can be returned with only one hit on the database. Read the docs about [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [prefetch-related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

Comment: The InlineModelAdmin stuffs was what I was looking for. Thanks!